# perl Net::SIP register sip account with useragent

Tags: perl, sip

**i try to register sip account with useragent**

> useragent:PolycomSoundPointIP-SPIP_450-UA/3
>
> i need some help  about how i can do it

```
 my $ua = Net::SIP::Simple->new(
  registrar =>  $host,
  domain =>  $host,
  from => $user,
  auth => [ $user,$pass ]
)|| return 0;

$ua->register()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should send a custom `User-Agent` header with the REGISTER request:

```
$ua->register('user-agent' => 'foo/bar');
```